# embed photo in email's body using mutt and html

Tags: html, email, embed, photo, mutt

i'm trying to embed a photo in an email body with HTML using mutt 1.9.4
after searching i cam up with this command:

```
mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "SUBJECT" -a IMAGE.jpeg -- user@example.com < mail.html
```

where the html file is:

```
<html>

<body> <img src="cid:image.jpeg" /> </body>

</html>
```

i get the photo as an attachment rather then embedded in the email's body

if i use this:

```
<body> <img src="image.jpeg" /> </body>
```

i get this broken image icon --> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo4XD.png)

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok the issue is that Google is blocking binary and base64 images, the solution was to add the photo from a URL:

```
<img src='http://www.example.com/image.jpg'>
```